# Bluetooth stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, thinkpad

Bluetooth suddenly stopped working.

Getting error: **Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)**

```
➜  ~ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-05-15 21:01:13 IST; 7min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 8616 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18757)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─8616 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad bluetoothd[8616]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad bluetoothd[8616]: Starting SDP server
May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad bluetoothd[8616]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad bluetoothd[8616]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x0b)
May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad bluetoothd[8616]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 15 21:01:13 ThinkPad bluetoothd[8616]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me on Ubuntu 22.10 was what I found at [this forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263172).

Run `sudo systemctl status bluetooth` and copy the ID of the device that won't connect.

For example, if it says:

```
Jan 31 11:57:00 Lenovo bluetoothd[753]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to FC:58:FA:DA:9B:D4: Connection refused (111)`
```

then copy `FC:58:FA:DA:9B:D4`.

Run `bluetoothctl`, then using that ID, `remove FC:58:FA:DA:9B:D4`, then `connect FC:58:FA:DA:9B:D4`.

It may start working immediately, or you might then need to turn it on in settings.

Answer (score 1):

There was a Ubuntu update recently (around 10 May 2021) [including Bluetooth package *bluez*](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/desktop-team-updates-monday-10th-may-2021/22194). You might [try reinstalling an earlier version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=bluez&searchon=names), e.g., [Focal Fossa, 5.53](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/bluez).

See also, [Beyond Linux form Scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/bluez.html).